# Load configuration file just once

Tags: php, routes, file-get-contents, altorouter

I'm working on my script to convert legacy links to seo friendly urls.

**index.php**

```
require 'AltoRouter.php';
$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->setBasePath('/router');

$urls = [
    'index.php?option=com_index&task=articles&id=1',
    'index.php?option=com_index&task=articles&slug=1-article-title',
    'index.php?option=com_index&task=articles.category&cid=100-category1',
    'index.php?option=com_shop&task=products&slug=100-amazing-product',
];

foreach($urls as $i=>$url) {
    echo $router->getSefUrl($url);
}
```

**AltoRouter.php**

```
...
public function getSefUrl($url) {

        $url_clean  = str_replace('index.php?', '', $url);
        parse_str($url_clean, $output);

        $component  = empty($output['option'])  ? 'com_index'   : $output['option'];
        $task               = empty($output['task'])        ? 'index'           : $output['task'];

        $path           = 'components/'.$component.'/routes/routes.json';
        $data           = json_decode(file_get_contents($path));

        if (!empty($data)) {
            foreach($data as $route) {
                $this->map($route[0], $route[1], $route[2], $route[2]);
            }
        }

        $route_info = $this->findUrlFromRoutes($task);
        return empty($route_info) ? $url : $this->generate($route_info->task, $output);
    }
...
```

My question: Every time when I'm using **getSefUrl** method I'm loading routes from external file. Is it ok? Or can I optimize code above some kind? If yes - how to?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid multiple fetches and decodes in your loop by breaking that out.

In AltoRouter.php

```
private $routes = array();

function getComponentRoutes($component)
{
    if(! isset($this->routes[$component])) {
        $path = 'components/'.$component.'/routes/routes.json';
        $this->routes[$component] = json_decode(file_get_contents($path));
    }

    return $this->routes[$component];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace that require with require_once or better use autoloading :

> You may define an __autoload() function which is automatically called
>   in case you are trying to use a class/interface which hasn't been
>   defined yet. By calling this function the scripting engine is given a
>   last chance to load the class before PHP fails with an error.

Create a folder and put all your required classs in this folder:

```
function __autoload($class) {
    require_once "Classes" . $class . '.php';
}
```